# Is there Any way to use the annotation @Binds instead of @Provides with a return type that require parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

any possible way to use provide this using bind annotation?

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideUtils(context: Context): Utils {
    return Utils(context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Utils` class has an `@Inject` constructor, e.g.

```
class Utils @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {
    // ...
}
```

... then you can bind it like so, and Dagger should be able to figure out how to create it (given that you're providing a `Context` somewhere):

```
@Singleton
@Binds
fun bindUtils(utils: Utils): Utils
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use constructor injection here. You **don't need `@Provides` *or* `@Binds`** if you use constructor injection.

```
@Singleton // scope on the class
class Utils @Inject constructor(private val context: Context)
```

That's all.